# Install Saxon-C on Linux 64 ARM

Tags: python, saxon, saxon-c

I downloaded:
https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1.zip

Unzipped and try to run:
./libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1

I get error about file not executable:
-bash: ./libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1: kan binair bestand Verkeerd uitvoerbaar bestand niet uitvoeren

cat /proc/version

Linux version 5.10.17-v8+ (dom@buildbot) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro                              8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1421 SMP PREEMPT                              Thu May 27 14:01:37 BST 2021

Can someone help?

Comment: Consider to translate "kan binair bestand Verkeerd uitvoerbaar bestand niet uitvoeren" to English, to allow us to better understand what error you get. Does your LINUX use bash or perhaps another shell (sh)?

Comment: Okay ... 'cannot run binary Wrong executable file'
It uses bash

Comment: Does "aarch64" mean it is not an Intel 64bit architecture?

Comment: I think you are right. 
CPU:  64-bit quad-core ARM Cortex-A72

Comment: I think you will need to wait for a response from Saxonica, I don't know whether their software supports ARM Linux.

Comment: Aha okay ... thanks Martin. 
I will wait for their response.

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!technical also gives an email address to contact them directly for ARM builds

Answer (score 3):

As already advised by direct support email, the Linux/ARM platform is not currently supported by Saxon/C. We (Saxonica) believe there's no technical obstacle to releasing it for this platform but it would need to be funded.